# formatting pdf for multiple pages with bleed

Tags: pdf

How should I format an A4 newsletter of 12 pages with bleed for pdf?

I am using Serif PagePlusX8.

Would it be correct to say bleed should be only on 3 sides as no bleed is needed on the 4th side?

Comment: what program are you using?

Comment: I am using Serif PagePlusX8. Not the most popular software, I'm afraid.

Comment: Do you consider 'bleed' as something to avoid as much as possible? If not, then why not bleed all around?

Answer (score 1):

**Speak with your print provider.** No one here can definitively state what any particular print provider may need.

In *many* cases, you need a PDF/X-1a file which consists of **single pages** with a *full* bleed (full = all 4 sides. Yes even a bleed for the gutter). The print provider will then impose the single pages to print correctly.

Caveat: Some online self-publishing services have **very specific** formatting guidelines for production. You should review any online service guidelines before generating a press-ready PDF.